# Disable Grid Scrollbars completely

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have recently started using Vaadin. I am stuck at one point. I can disable the scrollers. But the bars are visible when I resize the grid how can I hide the bars? You can see view attached image to get the issue.[image: Please have a look at this image to understand the issue]

Answer (score 2):

In order to hide the scrollbar, you need to override some CSS. Steps to overriding CSS are:

1. Set your theme in the application

   setTheme("yourThemeName")
2. Then in your Table you can use your own style

   table.addStyleName("yourStyleName")
3. Now you have to define your own CSS style in

> VAADIN/themes/yourThemeName/styles.css

```
@import "../reindeer/styles.css";
.v-table-mymodel .v-scrollable {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Once you've done this, clear your browser's cache and refresh your page. You should not see your scroll bar.